# The probability of throwing the total of at least $16$ with $4$ dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> The probability of throwing the total of at least $16$ with $4$ fair dice?

It seems difficult to count the favorable outcomes manually, because there are $6^4 = 1296$ outcomes in total, and with possible totals from $4$ to $24$, many of these outcomes are favorable.

Comment: These seem like two separate questions.

Comment: "X greater than or equal to Y" in fact is the same thing as "X not less than Y." Just a different way of saying it.

Answer (score 2):

The sample space is $6^4 = 1296$ since there are four dice. Now we need to count how many integer solutions there are to $a+b+c+d\ge 16$ where $1 \le a,b,c,d \le 6$.

We can count this using the inclusion-exclusion principle, or use generating functions. I will use the latter.

The number of integer solutions to $a+b+c+d=16$, for example, is the coefficient of $x^{16}$ in the expansion of
$$\left(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6\right)^4.$$
Similarly, the number of integer solutions to $a+b+c+d=17,18,\dots,24$ are the coefficients of $x^{17},x^{18},\dots,x^{24}$. Using your favorite CAS, the number of integer solutions to $a+b+c+d\ge 16$ is just the sum of those coefficients, which is $435$.

So the desired probability is $$\frac{435}{1296} \approx 0.335.$$

Answer (score 2):

I assume that each die is a fair 6-sided die with faces labeled 1,2,3,4,5,6 and we are interested in the sum of all four dice faces.

There are several approaches I can think of.  You could calculate the probability of throwing a total of 16, add that to the probability of throwing a 17, add that to 18, ... on up to 24 (max possible).  This is what was done above by Andrey with computer assistance.  Doing this in a test situation however where there is limited time, paperspace, and potentially no calculators allowed makes that approach rather cumbersome (but with a computer as shown it is very convenient).

For a less paper heavy approach, you can accomplish this in fewer steps by running two calculations and exploiting the symmetry.  You will need to calculate $P(x=14)$ and $P(x=13)$.  Notice that $P(x=15)=P(x=13)$ and that $P(x\leq 12) = P(x\geq 16)$.

You have that $1 = P(x\leq 12) + P(x=13) + P(x=14) + P(x=15) + P(x\geq 16)$

$1 = 2\cdot P(x\geq 16) + 2\cdot P(x=13) + P(x=14)$

$\frac{1}{2}\cdot(1 - P(x=14) - 2\cdot P(x=13)) = P(x\geq 16)$

To continue, we try to find the chance of throwing a total sum of exactly 14.  Had there been just two dice it would have been quick and easy to bruteforce an answer, but here we'll use a more delicate approach.  Stars and Bars.

Imagine 10 dots and three lines.  The number of dots to the left of the first line will represent one less than the number that appears on the first die.  The number of dots inbetween the first and second line will represent one less than the second die result, etc.  Thus, there are $\binom{13}{3}$ possible scenarios that give a result of exactly 14 if we ignore the fact that we cannot have a result of 7 or higher on a single die.  By inclusion exclusion principle then, subtract the results that violate this.  Note, it cannot be violated by two or more dice simultaneously.  The number of results that violate this would be $4\cdot \binom{7}{3}$ (achieved by first choosing which die was the violator of the condition (4) and then how many ways to distribute the remaining 7 points achieved again by stars and bars with a change of variable)

So, $P(x=14) = (\binom{13}{3} - 4\cdot \binom{7}{3})/6^4$ (dividing by $6^4$ since that is the sample space size).

By a similar method, we calculate $P(x=13)$ to be $(\binom{12}{3} - 4\cdot \binom{6}{3})/6^4$

Thus, the probability is $\frac{1}{2}(1 - (\binom{13}{3} - 4\cdot \binom{7}{3})/6^4 - (\binom{12}{3} - 4\cdot \binom{6}{3})/6^4) = \frac{435}{1296}$, agreeing with the answer by Andrey.

Comment: Nice, I like the use of the symmetry! I'm having trouble counting the violating cases, but I'll keep thinking about it!

Comment: originally, it is the integral solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 14$ subject to $x_i \geq 1$.  Make a change of variable $x_i - 1 = y_i \geq 0$ and $\sum y_i = 10$ in order to use the formula $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$ to get $\binom{10+4-1}{4-1} = \binom{13}{3}$.  To handle the violating cases it is the same except $x_1 \geq 7$ and $x_i\geq 1$ for $i\neq 1$ so make change of variables $x_1 - 7 = y_1 \geq 0$ and $x_i - 1 = y_i\geq 0$ for the others with $\sum y_i = 14-7-3 = 4$, hence the $\binom{4+4-1}{4-1} = \binom{7}{3}$.  Repeat that four times for each possible violating die.

Comment: Oh right! It's just the inclusion-exclusion principle, thanks! I was stuck in the stars and bars mindset.